# Unit Testing dynamically imported React Component

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, enzyme, react-loadable

I have a very simple React component that uses [`react-loadable`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) to dynamically import another component. The code looks something akin to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import LoaderComponent from 'path/to/LoaderComponent';


export default outerLoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('path/to/innerComponent'),
  loading() {
    return <LoaderComponent />
  }
});
```

I am attempting to test this component by using Enzyme to `mount` `outerLoadableComponent`, which creates a wrapper around `outerLoadableComponent` where I can see that the `LoaderComponent` wrapping it has the `loadingState` set to true. However, I am stuck at the point where the inner `import` does not resolve. It seems to be a promise that would only resolve should the import actually go through, however even with some timeouts, it does not work:

```
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

it('should render the loading state, and innerComponent', (done) => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <outerLoadableComponent />
  );

  expect(wrapper.loading).to.be.true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(wrapper.loading).to.be.false;
    expect(wrapper.loaded).to.exist; // loaded state returns a function
    expect(wrapper.find(innerComponent)).to.exist;
    done();
  }, 500);
});
```

My `babel-rc` has `dynamic-import-node` so running this outside of the test works all fine. But there seems to be no clear/documented way of mocking (with sinon) the results of an `import` promise. Any ideas?

Comment: Sinon deals with stubbing objects, not interfacing with module loaders. We do document how to do it, though: https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/